# Angular Failing to Route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

```
**Unable to Route**
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="mymodule">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Index</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="angular-resource.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script></head>
<body>
<h1>Routing</h1>
 <a href="#/Course">Course</a>
 <a href="#/Students">Students</a>
 <div ng-view></div>
 </body>
```

**ANGULARJS**

```
var myapp = angular.module("mymodule",["ngRoute"]).config(function($routeprovider){$routeprovider


  .when("/Students",{


      templateUrl:"Students.html",
      controller:"studentcontroller"
  })



  .when("/Course",{


      templateUrl:"Course.html",
      controller:"CourseController"
  })});  
myapp.controller("studentcontroller",["$scope",function($scope){

$scope.message="Hello Welcome to students page";}]);

myapp.controller("CourseController",["$scope",function($scope){
 $scope.alert="Welcome to course page";}])
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG9rK.png

*Iam new to angular and when i trying to route iam  unable to do that it throws me an error.Please if any one can fix this problem i would really appriciate that.Thanks *

Comment: Please help me out with this code.I tried hell lot of times but it shows me erorr..Thanks

Comment: did you define controllers?

Comment: I did but it shows me the same error.

Comment: without looking at you full code, difficult to identify root issue. can you add complete code

Answer (score 0):

Change both instances of `$routeprovider` into `$routeProvider`. e.g.

```
var myapp = angular.module("mymodule",["ngRoute"])
.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when("/Students",{
        templateUrl:"Students.html",
        controller:"studentcontroller"
    })
    .when("/Course",{
        templateUrl:"Course.html",
        controller:"CourseController"
    })
})
```

Comment: Hey thanks it's working.On home page i-e index.html it is displaying Student.html stuff and when iam trying to click the course anchor tag it's not displaying anything unless i have to type it  manually in URL i-e ( /Course).. Again thanks for your help.

Comment: May be it has problem in template url or may be in anchor tag where iam giving the path..Iam not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Rename `$routeprovider` to `$routeProvider`.

Remember, when working in angular, the argument names should be exactly the same as your instructor tells you (I see it is w3schools).

Comment: Thanks it's working now.But when iam trying to do it by clicking anchor tag it's not working unless i have to do it manually by typing in URL.(i-e /Course and for Students page just / ).Wondering why iam not able to work with anchor tag event. Could you help me out  my freind.Thanks

Comment: Are you using a local server (localhost) or a `file:///` url. Your browser can't load Students.html or Course.html if your using `file:///` urls. Try running on a local server. You can also try replacing your anchor hrefs with `#!/Course.html` or `#!/students.html`.

Comment: Thanks.I tried doing earlier in Sublime Text Editor it was showing URL(file:///) and when i did in Webstorm IDE the URL was (local host) wondering how because i did not installed any local server  in my machine..Not Xampp either.How does that even work???

Comment: There are several other options other than XAMPP that can make `localhost` servers (like NODE.js in WebStorm). Also, I have seen that firefox browser allows you to load local `file:///` urls with AJAX. Give it a try.